# Spring Boot Redis getting connection refused exception when using Redis

Tags: docker, spring-boot, redis, docker-compose

I have a small application where use I use redis for cache and Spring Boot. Application runs successfully in local but when I try to dockerize it, I'm getting connection refuse exception.

It's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  my-application:
    image: my-application:latest
    container_name: my-application
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    hostname: my-application

  redis:
    image: redis
    command: [ "redis-server", "--protected-mode", "no" ]
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:7

VOLUME /tmp

ADD my-application-0.0.1.jar my-application-0.0.1.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "my-application-0.0.1.jar"]
```

When I check docker console, I saw that redis starts in standalone mode

What I'm missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

in your `application.properties`. If your application is listen on `127.0.0.1` in the container, you won't be able to reach it from your host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the redis host to the name of the redis configuration in the docker compose file, in this case - **redis**

It can be configured by two ways:

- changing property file *spring.redis.host=redis*
- setting host in manual config (redis or jedis) `redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("redis");`

Also, in my case, I did not use volume in my docker files, so to use the new jar file you need to do all 3 steps of launching docker compose (*apart from clean build in gradle or clean install in maven*):

- docker-compose down
- docker-compose build
- docker-compose up

I hope this is useful to someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed with (docker-compose.yml)

```
 cache:
    image: redis
    ...
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

then in application.properties `spring.redis.host=cache`

and eventually

```
@Value("${spring.redis.host}")
String redisHost
...
redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(redisHost);
```

I think, in docker network, service name with same name of image is causing issues and ending with docker not being able to create connections to redis host.